# SwipeRefreshLayout :refresh layout only when the top portion of the layout is swiped

Tags: android

Am using SwipeRefreshLayout for a webview and I need to refresh only when I swipe the top portion of the webview . Is there any possible way to do this.I have the SwipeRefreshLayout.java class an in that I have  reduced the REFRESH_TRIGGER_DISTANCE value but still no luck in that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'top portion'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to restrict handling of swipe in some area, You just need to block handling of some touch events in `SwipeRefreshLayout.onTouchEvent()`.
For example, if you don't want to let swipe on bottom half, then use smth like the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    boolean handled = false;
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final MotionEvent eventCopy = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
            final float eventY = eventCopy.getY();

            // Handle only top half
            if (eventY < (getHeight() / 2)) {
                mCurrPercentage = 0;
                mDownEvent = eventCopy;
                mPrevY = mDownEvent.getY();
            } else {
                mDownEvent = null;
            }
        }
            break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.swipe"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.androidexample.swipescreen.SwipeScreenExample" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

SwipeScreenExample activity is as follows.

```
public class SwipeScreenExample extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener{
            private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.swipe_screen);

                // Detect touched area 
                detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
         this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
       return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }
    @Override
     public void onSwipe(int direction) {
      String str = "";

      switch (direction) {

      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : str = "Swipe Right";
                                               break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  str = "Swipe Left";
                                                     break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  str = "Swipe Down";
                                                     break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    str = "Swipe Up";
                                                     break;

      }
       Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDoubleTap() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

  }
```

GestureActivity is as follows.

```
public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener{

         public final static int SWIPE_UP    = 1;
         public final static int SWIPE_DOWN  = 2;
         public final static int SWIPE_LEFT  = 3;
         public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

         public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
         public final static int MODE_SOLID       = 1;
         public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC     = 2;

         private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //just an unlikely number
         private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
         private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
         private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

     private int mode             = MODE_DYNAMIC;
     private boolean running      = true;
     private boolean tapIndicator = false;

     private Activity context;
     private GestureDetector detector;
     private SimpleGestureListener listener;

     public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

      this.context = context;
      this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
      this.listener = sgl;
     }

     public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

       if(!this.running)
      return; 

       boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

       if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
       else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

         if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
           event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
         else if (result)
           event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
         else if(this.tapIndicator){
          event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
          this.tapIndicator = false;
         }

       }
       //else just do nothing, it's Transparent
     }

     public void setMode(int m){
      this.mode = m;
     }

     public int getMode(){
      return this.mode;
     }

     public void setEnabled(boolean status){
      this.running = status;
     }

     public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance){
      this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
     }

     public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance){
      this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
     }

     public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance){
      this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
     }

     public int getSwipeMaxDistance(){
      return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
     }

     public int getSwipeMinDistance(){
      return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
     }

     public int getSwipeMinVelocity(){
      return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
     }

     @Override
         public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
           float velocityY) {

          final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
          final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

          if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
           return false;

          velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
          velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
                boolean result = false;

          if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
           if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
           else
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

           result = true;
          }
          else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
           if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
           else
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

           result = true;
          }

           return result;
         }

     @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
      this.tapIndicator = true;
      return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg) {
      this.listener.onDoubleTap();;
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg) {
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

      if(this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC){        // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an
         arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);      //action which will be converted to an ACTION_UP later.
         this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
      }  

      return false;
     }

        static interface SimpleGestureListener{
         void onSwipe(int direction);
         void onDoubleTap();
     }

    }
```

I hope this will be very helpful for you, Here i have added left,right,top,down all directions.

Comment: Thnkx.This might be helpful for others who visit this question

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions worked for me. But just this piece of code did.

```
  @Override
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
   {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
     if(y>800){
         swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
     }else {
         swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
     }
     Log.e("yy",""+y);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I kept a flag to decide if I have to refresh or not.

In XML

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/swipeId"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"> ... 
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout >
```

In Code

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeId);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new 
    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            if (toRefresh)
                startActivity(new Intent(context, LocationCurrentStatus.class));
            else
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

 @Override
 public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    final int action = event.getAction();
    boolean handled = false;
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        final MotionEvent eventCopy = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
        final float eventY = eventCopy.getY();

        if (eventY > getHeight()) {
            System.out.println("disabling");
            toRefresh = false;
        } else {
            System.out.println("enabling");
            toRefresh = true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

private float getHeight() {
    // your code to find threshold height
}
```